# Anti-spyware boot disk

Tags: anti-spyware

Would you know of a great anti-spyware/anti-virus boot disks to quickly repair a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question after having done research.

Many antivirus vendors have their rescue-CD available online for on-boot scanning. Very time saving.

- AVG Rescue CD
- Kaspersky Rescue CD
- BitDefender Rescue CD
- Trinity Rescue CD

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most robust solution is to build one yourself using something like [Bart's PE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) to configure your own software. This creates a bootable environment that can run most Windows applications. Just throw your favorite anti virus and anti-spyware program (Like MalwareByte's Anti-Malware or Lavasoft Ad-Aware) and go at it.

You could also try running them under windows Safe Mode of course.